# Does clang-format have a way of running a custom regex and then do an operation on the match?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang-format

Does clang-format has a implementation for writing custom regex expressions to recognize some patterns and then doing an operation on that code and normal formatting wont run on that part of the code? I want to be able to have my forward declarations like below, but clang-format doesn't have settings for it.

```
namespace One::Two { class MyClassA; }
namespace One::Two { using MyClassAUPtr = std::unique_ptr<MyClassA>; }

namespace One::Three { class MyClassC; }
namespace One::Three { using MyClassCUPtr = std::unique_ptr<MyClassC>; }
```

Comment: As far as I know no, and it's a very bad ideea to parse C++ code with regex anyway.

Comment: Okay, What does clang use for parsing?

Comment: If you want to replace stuff with a regex, you can use `sed` in combination with `find`.

Comment: Guess I could run a custom script after clang-format

Comment: If you need to do this on a large scale with many name collisions, then there are tools for that too. [clang-rename](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-rename.html) seems promising and apparently it's possible to write custom tools using [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html). I haven't used either tool though.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Clang-format doesn't have anything like what you've asked for here...

A workaround for this is to temporarily disable clang-format for that piece of code. That can be done with clang-format pragma comments.

```cpp
// clang-format off
namespace One::Two { class MyClassA; }
namespace One::Two { using MyClassAUPtr = std::unique_ptr<MyClassA>; }

namespace One::Three { class MyClassC; }
namespace One::Three { using MyClassCUPtr = std::unique_ptr<MyClassC>; }
// clang-format on
```

---

I would also like to answer your question below your original thread:

> Okay, What does clang use for parsing?

Clang gathers its own representation of the C++ source code in a data structure named an "Abstract Syntax Tree", or AST for short. Clang-format is a tool built on top of Clang's LibTooling so it uses the same C/C++/ObjC/ObjC++ parser that Clang does.

The AST is a large and complex tree, and its source code spans around 100 thousands lines of code. I imagine you're better off mometarily disabling clang-format for this use case instead of writing your own tool.

You can read more about the Clang AST here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html